# Singleton type as a type member

Tags: scala, shapeless, type-safety, refined

I'm trying to define a type member to be a singleton type. Here is my attempt:

```
import shapeless.syntax.singleton._

trait Test{
    type Blocked <: Boolean
}

def f(t: Test{ type Blocked = false.narrow }) = ??? // does not compile

def f(t: Test{ type Blocked = false }) = ??? // argument is parsed as t: Test{ type Blocked = Boolean }
```

Is there a way to set a type member to a singleton type (`Boolean(false)` in my case)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `def f(t: Test{ type Blocked = false }) = ??? // argument is parsed as t: Test{ type Blocked = Boolean }`

`Blocked` becomes literal singleton type `false`; note how  `f(true)` is rejected bellow

```
scala> trait Test{
     |     type Blocked <: Boolean
     | }
trait Test

scala> val v = new Test { type Blocked = false }
val v: Test{type Blocked = false} = $anon$1@34aa8b61

scala> def f(x: v.Blocked) = x
def f(x: v.Blocked): v.Blocked

scala> f(false)
val res0: v.Blocked = false

scala> f(true)
         ^
       error: type mismatch;
        found   : Boolean(true)
        required: v.Blocked
           (which expands to)  false
```